# SQLClient not working when referencing other project - Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, sqlclient

I'm trying to convert an old Silverlight app into something shiny new as a dev team of one. It's an internal app for the company and is only being updated/replaced now that Microsoft has started forcing sites to open in Edge over IE (and employees who get new laptops can't get Silverlight on them very easily)

I was hoping to create a new front end in Blazor/Razor and connect it to the still functional C# backend, however when I try to load data into a table from a pre-existing SQLConnection method I get an error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified."

I'm referencing this method from the @code section of a razor page:

```
@code {
    public InternalDAL.PaymentDataSet pendingTransactions = 
    InternalDAL.PaymentDatabaseHelper.GetPaymentRecordsPending(null);
}
```

That works so far as calling the method GetPaymentRecordsPending(), which in turn digs deeper in the InternalDAL project:

```
public static PaymentDataSet GetPaymentRecordsPending(string Id) {

    PaymentDataSet data = new PaymentDataSet ();

    data.EnforceConstraints = false;

    PaymentRecordTableAdapter adapter = new PaymentRecordTableAdapter();

    adapter.FillWithPendingById (data.PaymentRecord, Id);
    
    return data;

}
```

But it tanks on the line calling "FillWithPendingById", and returns the SQLClient error above.

I can navigate to that method within the same InternalDAL project but it is within a separate file in that project; InternalDAL.PaymentDataSet.Designer.cs

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
[global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectMethodType.Fill, false)]

public virtual int FillWithPendingById(PaymentDataSet.PaymentRecordDataTable dataTable, string Id) {

    this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[3];

    if ((StudentId == null)) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = 
        global::System.DBNull.Value;
    }
    else {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(Id));
    }

    if ((this.ClearBeforeFill == true)) {
        dataTable.Clear();
    }

    int returnValue = this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);

    return returnValue;
}
```

There's one more layer to this process (CommandCollection), but I don't think the code gets that far, which sets up the SQL Query. It just chooses from a list of four stored procs that all use the same connection.

I have tried using nuget to import SQLClient into my new Blazor front end, but there was no change.

I've confirmed that the InternalDAL is already referencing system.data.sqlclient (and has been running on an active server for my company for years)

I've copied the connection strings from the old web.config file and double checked them as well.

I would like to avoid rewriting the queries from scratch, because I've only just started this project and having to redo the backend as well is going to make it unfeasible. I would really like to be able to correct a reference/package somewhere and for the old backend to start working with no trouble.

*Update*

I have updated the target framework for the InternalDAL project from 3.5 to 4.8, nothing new seems to have broken but the error remains.

Comment: I was going to try to help but I won't spend time to try to understand code that is unnecessarily hard to read. I'm sure I'm not the only one. If you want to maximise your chances of getting the help you want, you should make the effort to format your code properly, for easy reading.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have attempted to pretty it up a bit, hope that makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this (and uncovered new errors, but not this one anymore) by updating the NuGet package for both my new Blazor project and the pre-existing InternalDAL project to v5.1.0

I then did a find & replace across the whole solution and changed every reference to `System.Data.SqlClient` to `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`